# manage.py collectstatic command not found, Django 1.5.1

Tags: python, django

I am very new to python and when I run the

`$ python manage.py collectstatic`

command, It returns

'unknown command: 'collectstatic''

From what I have found from research there seems to be a problem with settings.py, here is my settings.py:

```
import os
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'basic_code.sqlite3',                     
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static/media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static/static-only')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static/static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'basic_code.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'basic_code.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static/templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'contact',
)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Thank you so much! I really appreciate any help.

Comment: type "python manage.py" in the terminal and see if you see "collectstatic" in the output list.  If it is there then you should be able to run it.

Comment: Is your settings file being loaded by the `manage.py` command? Try explicitly specifying it using `python manage.py collectstatic --settings=path.to.settings`. Note that this uses a dotted path without the `py` extension included rather than a filepath.

Comment: Aron, it is not in the list when I type python manage.py

Comment: Jonafato, it throws 2 errors when I do this. "Import by file name is not supported" and "could not import settings"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change media url from /media to /media/

Next time if you encounter such a problem, try runserver and check trace if it does not work.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much I really appreciate your help! I was sitting at this for hours. You're the man!